# What’s the term for an acronym that refers to another acronym?

Tags: acronyms, initialisms

For example, AIM stands for AOL Instant Messenger, and AOL stands for American OnLine.
This isn’t quite the same thing as a recursive acronym, which refers to itself. Maybe the term is nested acronym?

Comment: Please check standard dictionaries for the default usage of 'acronym' (versus 'initialism'). Using this, BBC is an initialism rather than an acronym, while  NASA (see [Kennedy Space Center.com](https://www.kennedyspacecenter.com/blog/18/sce-to-aux-nasa-acronyms)) is an acronym. // AOL is obviously an initialism; how is AIM pronounced?

Comment: Unsure if this is an actual answer. I have come across **TLA**. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tla) says it is *three-letter abbreviation* or *three-letter acronym*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Don't forget about the **ETLA**. That's an *extended three-letter abbreviation*. Because always there shall be three letters in your abbreviations. ***Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out.***

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Not sure it's terribly relevant, but AIM is an acronym, not an initialism. At least, it was in my neck of the woods when it was a relevant program.

Comment: @MichaelS 'What’s the term for an acronym that refers to another acronym? ... For example, AIM ...' would not be using the standard default definition (and the one used on ELU) for 'acronym' were AIM not pronounced as a word. Mixing stipulative definitions willy-nilly is confusing and unhelpful. Mind you, 'nested acronym' muddies the waters perhaps irretrievably.

Comment: I personally like the ironic acronym CAT where CAT stands for Campaign Against TLAs and TLAs is Three Letter Acronyms.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're correct, it is in fact a *[nested acronym](https://www.allacronyms.com/aa-types-of-acronyms)*:

> **nested acronym**: an acronym where one of the letters represents another acronym. e.g.
> AIM (AOL Instant Messenger)

You're also correct that it's not a *recursive acronym*, of which GNU (GNU's Not Unix) is the most infamous example:

> **recursive acronym**: an acronym which refers to itself in the expression for which it
> stands. e.g. VISA standing for Visa International Service Association

Comment: My favorite is the *mutually recursive* acronym in *GNU Hurd*, where "Hurd" stands for *HIRD of Unix-Replacing Daemons*, where "HIRD" stands for *HURD of Interfaces Representing Depth*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Wooof! That is evil! :-)

Comment: my favorite recursive acronym would have to be PHP, which stands for "PHP Hypertext Preprocessor"

Comment: I like GNU itself, the recursive "GNU is not Unix".

Comment: And, in the GNU vein, there's MINCE - "Mince Is Not Complete Emacs".

Comment: "VISA standing for Visa International Service Association" unclear if "Visa" here refers to [VISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Inc.) or [visa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/visa#Noun) or what.

Answer (score 19):

It is also called a ***macronym*** or a ***multi-layered acronym***, although the term "nested acronym" is more common:

> A **macronym**, or **nested acronym**, is an acronym in which one or more letters stand for acronyms (or abbreviations) themselves. **The word "macronym" is a portmanteau of "macro-" and "acronym"**.
>
> Some examples of **macronyms** are:
>
> - [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHR) stands for "XML HTTP Request", in which "[XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)" is "Extensible Markup Language", and [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) stands for "HyperText Transfer Protocol"
> - [POWER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Power_microprocessors) stands for "Performance Optimization With Enhanced RISC", in which "[RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC)" stands for "Reduced Instruction Set Computing"
> - [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) stands for "VHSIC Hardware Description Language", in which "[VHSIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHSIC)" stands for "Very High Speed Integrated Circuit"
> - [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSD) stands for "XML Schema Definition", in which "[XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)" stands for "Extensible Markup Language"
> - [AIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_Instant_Messenger) stands for "AOL Instant Messenger", in which "[AOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL)" originally stood for "America Online"
> - [HASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston_Automatic_Spooling_Priority) stood for "Houston Automatic Spooling Priority", but "[spooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooling)" itself was an acronym: "simultaneous peripheral operations on-line"
> - [VORTAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VORTAC) stands for "VOR+TACAN", in which "[VOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range)" is "VHF omnidirectional range" (where VHF = Very High Frequency radio) and "TAC" is short for [TACAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TACAN), which stands for "Tactical Air Navigation"
>
> (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym#Macronyms/nested_acronyms))

---

Here's a deeply nested acronym (for fun): [VITAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL-VITAL), which expands to "[VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) Initiative Towards [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASIC) Libraries", which further expands to "[VHSIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHSIC) Hardware Description Language Initiative Towards Application-Specific Integrated Circuit Libraries", which further expands to "Very High Speed Integrated Circuit Hardware Description Language Initiative Towards Application-Specific Integrated Circuit Libraries". That's **15** words long when fully expanded!

Comment: VORTAC seems irregular because TAC expands to TACAN which is an abbreviation which itself expands to something that itself is more of an abbreviation than an acronym or initialism.